# Flask says its running but the code is not showing in the browser

Tags: flask, windows-10

I am trying to run Flask code on Windows 10 machine.The command line says that the Flask app is being served.

```
(HelloWorld) C:\Users\binoy\dev\HelloWorld>python HelloWorld.py
 * Serving Flask app "HelloWorld" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 211-440-231
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2019 11:27:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2019 11:27:18] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2019 11:28:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2019 11:28:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2019 11:30:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2019 11:34:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

But when I open the browser I get the message `404 Not Found`

Any idea why I am not able to see the App

Answer (score 2):

Thanks got it fixed. I had to change the code.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True, debug=True)
```

I had inserted

```
`if _name_=='_main_':`
```

before

```
 `@app.route("/") before `@app.route("/")`
```

Now it's running!!